# Как на php/nodejs сделать роутер c вложенными url?

Tags: php, node.js, маршрутизация, route, router

Как правильно сделать роутер что бы url был вложенным, и количество вложенности нам не известно. 
Можно вот так (nodejs)

```
Route.get('/:category', 'FrontController')
Route.get('/:category:subcategory', 'FrontController')
Route.get('/:category:subcategory:page', 'FrontController')
```

Но так мы ограничим нашу вложенность до 3-х ресурсов.

Подскажите как вы это делаете. Не важно на каком языке, главное принцип работы.

**UPD.** Возможно немного не так объяснил, но получить любою страницу можно так

`Route.get('*', 'FrontController')`

то есть через звездочку, так будет обрабатываться любой запрос.
Да в принципе и такой роутер примет любой запрос

```
Route.get('/:category', 'FrontController')
```

Вопрос в том как проверить к примеру такой адрес **/parent/parent/page/** существуют ли эти страницы и является ли parent родителем page. Короче говоря нужен принцип работы как в cms

Вот так можно получить массив имен страниц из адреса

```
request.url().split( '/' ) // [ 'qwe', 'asd', 'zxc' ]
```

И sql запросом получить страницы по условию

```
`WHERE alias IN ([ 'qwe', 'asd', 'zxc' ])`
```

ответ из базы

```
[ { id: 1, alias: 'qwe', parent: 0 },
  { id: 2, alias: 'asd', parent: 1 },
  { id: 3, alias: 'zxc', parent: 2 } ]
```

Вот теперь у меня мозг пришел в тупик, во первых правильно ли я вообще начал решать проблему, во вторых никак не пойму как это все правильно перебрать (

Comment: На любом языке это делается с помощью регулярных выражений.

Comment: На Node можно сделать банальным RegExp'ом

Comment: или можно использовать String.prototype.startsWith() , в данном примере различие только в начале, так что такой вариант тоже можно использовать